# Android Keystore hardware-backed attestation not working on Samsung Galaxy S8

Tags: java, android, android-keystore

I've been trying to verify an attestation root certificate by following this [example from Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-key-attestation/blob/master/server/src/main/java/com/android/example/KeyAttestationExample.java)

However the root certificate from my device (Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 9) does not match the ***GOOGLE_ROOT_CERTIFICATE*** in the example and fails the check at line 441 in the example.

But my device's root certificate does match when I switch out the *GOOGLE_ROOT_CERTIFICATE* in the example for the certificate posted here: https://gist.github.com/herrjemand/a612608dfbb2bc136aba57c64ff4a04c#file-androidkey-attestation-root-pem

I noticed that both my device's root certificate and the certificate posted in that last link have a Common Name value of *"Android Keystore Software Attestation Root."* Does this mean that my device does not support hardware-backed key attestation?

(I have verified that the keys themselves are stored in secure hardware by using the *isInsideSecureHardware()* *function* in my **Android** **app** that generates the keys.)

Answer (score 6):

Devices launched with Nougat or previous were not required to support hardware-backed attestation, but instead of simply failing when an attestation is requested, they generate an attestation in software, and this is what you're seeing: a software attestation to a hardware-based key.  If you examine the attestation record (See https://github.com/googlesamples/android-key-attestation for sample code) you'll find that the attestation security level is KM_SECURITY_LEVEL_SOFTWARE but the keymaster security level is KM_SECURITY_LEVEL_TRUSTED_ENVIRONMENT.  This means that the key is actually in secure hardware but the attestation was generated by Android software.

How does this differ from an attestation generated by secure hardware, with the Google attestation root?

If an attacker has compromised a given Android device's software sufficiently to be able to alter the operation of the keystore daemon, they can make the software generate whatever sort of attestation they want.  They can make it generate an attestation record claiming that a key is in secure hardware when it is not, or a record that claims that a key has certain restrictions on its usage when it doesn't.  What they can't do is sign it with a key that chains back to the Google root.

However, an attacker who has compromised Android cannot alter the operation of the secure hardware.  If the attestation chains back to the Google root, then you can have confidence that the attestation was generated in secure hardware and is therefore secure against attackers who can compromise the Android OS.

Further, if you check the revocation status of the certificates in the chain and none are revoked, you can also be confident that there are no *known* vulnerabilities in the secure hardware that could enable compromise of the key or attestation.  If a vulnerability is discovered, or if the attestation keys are found to have leaked, or some other problem, Google will revoke the attestation signing key and you'll see this in the revocation chain.

To summarize:

1. If you see an attestation chain that doesn't end in the Google root, you should assume that either:

   - The device is not a Google Play device, or
   - The device was launched with a pre-Oreo version of Android.
2. If you see an attestation chain that contains a revoked certificate, you should assume that there has been some problem.  Check the revocation data to see what.

In either case, the fact that the attestation isn't fully trustworthy doesn't mean you should assume the device is compromised or in some way bad.  For that matter, a fully-good attestation doesn't prove that the *device* is secure and uncompromised, it just proves that your keystore keys are hosted in secure hardware, which means you can assume that the keys cannot be extracted or used in ways that the hardware should prevent.

Sorry if this seems very nuanced and complicated.  Security is subtle and never a simple "yes" or "no".